# How to add together items in list

Tags: python, pandas

Each number in R_Distance, R_GoingDesc, and Race Count correspond, respectively. For each distance, I want to add the race count for 'good' and 'unknown' tracks together. In the example below, I would be adding 20 + 2 for 1000m, 28 + 1 for 1200m, and 13 + 2 for 1600m. Please also see below for desired output of list.

List:

```
{
    'Track': 'adelaide river', 
    'R_Distance': [1000.0, 1000.0, 1000.0, 1200.0, 1200.0, 1200.0, 1600.0, 1600.0, 1600.0], 
    'R_GoingDesc': ['firm', 'good', 'unknown', 'firm', 'good', 'unknown', 'firm', 'good', 'unknown'],
    'Race Count': [6, 20, 2, 4, 28, 1, 2, 13, 2]
}
```

Desired output of list (20 + 2 = 22, 28 + 1 = 29, 13 + 2 = 15. Adding together the numbers that correspond with 'good' and 'unknown'):

```
{
    'Track': 'adelaide river', 
    'R_Distance': [1000.0, 1000.0, 1200.0, 1200.0, 1600.0, 1600.0], 
    'R_GoingDesc': ['firm', 'good', 'firm', 'good', 'firm', 'good'],
    'Race Count': [6, 22, 4, 29, 2, 15]
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how you arrived at that order.

Comment: So unknown has gone from the output, and good has been replaced by the values of good and unknown?

Comment: 20 + 2 = 22, 28 + 1 = 29, 13 + 2 = 15. Adding together the numbers that correspond with 'good' and 'unknown'

Comment: Why did you tag pandas? If you want to use pandas, shouldn't the first question be how to put your data in a [DataFrame format](https://www.w3schools.com/python/pandas/pandas_dataframes.asp)?..

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged the question as `pandas`, you can do this with `groupby` after manipulating your raw data slightly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Track': 'adelaide river', 
    'R_Distance': [1000.0, 1000.0, 1000.0, 1200.0, 1200.0, 1200.0, 1600.0, 1600.0, 1600.0], 
    'R_GoingDesc': ['firm', 'good', 'unknown', 'firm', 'good', 'unknown', 'firm', 'good', 'unknown'],
    'Race Count': [6, 20, 2, 4, 28, 1, 2, 13, 2]
})

#replace "unknown" with "good" for the grouping
df["R_GoingDesc"] = df["R_GoingDesc"].replace("unknown","good")

#groupby and calculate the sum
df["Race Count"] = df.groupby(["R_GoingDesc", "R_Distance"])["Race Count"].transform("sum")

#drop duplicates
df = df.drop_duplicates(ignore_index=True)

>>> df
            Track  R_Distance R_GoingDesc  Race Count
0  adelaide river      1000.0        firm           6
1  adelaide river      1000.0        good          22
2  adelaide river      1200.0        firm           4
3  adelaide river      1200.0        good          29
4  adelaide river      1600.0        firm           2
5  adelaide river      1600.0        good          15
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = {
     'Track': 'adelaide river',
     'R_Distance': [1000.0, 1000.0, 1000.0, 1200.0, 1200.0, 1200.0, 1600.0, 1600.0, 1600.0],
     'R_GoingDesc': ['firm', 'good', 'unknown', 'firm', 'good', 'unknown', 'firm', 'good', 'unknown'],
     'Race Count': [6, 20, 2, 4, 28, 1, 2, 13, 2]
    }


tmp_dict = {}
distance_list = []
count_list = []
tmp_list = []

#formatting the existing dictionary
for i in range(len(a['R_Distance'])):
    if a['R_Distance'][i] in tmp_dict.keys():
        tmp_dict[a['R_Distance'][i]].append([a['R_GoingDesc'][i], a['Race Count'][i]])
    else:
        tmp_dict[a['R_Distance'][i]] = [[a['R_GoingDesc'][i], a['Race Count'][i]]]

#updating the dictionary
for key,value_list in tmp_dict.items():
    final_number = int()
    for values in value_list:
        if 'firm' in values:
            tmp_list.append(values[0])
            distance_list.append(key)
            count_list.append(values[1])
        elif 'good' in values:
            final_number = final_number + values[1]
            tmp_list.append(values[0])
            distance_list.append(key)
        elif 'unknown' in values:
            final_number = final_number + values[1]
    count_list.append(final_number)
a.update({'R_Distance':distance_list,'R_GoingDesc':tmp_list,'Race Count':count_list})

>> a
{'Track': 'adelaide river', 
'R_Distance': [1000.0, 1000.0, 1200.0, 1200.0, 1600.0, 1600.0], 
'R_GoingDesc': ['firm', 'good', 'firm', 'good', 'firm', 'good'],
'Race Count': [6, 22, 4, 29, 2, 15]}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).